# how to append vuetify icons based on type and condition?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

i have a component here called taglist in which i have added an icon and another component named gamelist component. I have certain fields in gamelist component namely title, subtitle, rating etc. In taglist component i have an icon which is also a router link. how can i append the icon in the gamelist component based on only the title field and if a certain condition is true?

I am not sure if it will be a prop or something else?

In My gamelist component:-

```
<template>
  <tag-list 
    :title="title"
    :subtitle="subtitle"
    :rating="rating"" />
</template>
```

In my Taglist component:-

```
   <template>
     <router-link :append-icon>
       <v-icon>create<v-icon>
     <router-link>
   </template>

  <script>
    export default {
        return {
            data() {
               switchClass: false
           }
          }
       }
   </script>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.